# SHA-1 for same string found different in C++ and JAVA

Tags: java, encryption, hash, sha1, javax.crypto

SHA-1 for the same string is different is Java and C++

String to hash - 38902566

SHA-1 in java - 6ffc3d4038943971cd91db0cf0f3de8ecf1b2853 (confirmed online sha1 tool produces same)

SHA-1 in C++ - 093288D2933CE7D55295450EBFE711F3E1AE3BF2

Java implementation:

```
  MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
  byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(customerId.getBytes());
  BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);

  String hashtext = no.toString(16);

  while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
    hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
  }
  return hashtext;
```

C++ implementation

```
int hash_SHA1(const char* cid, int len, char* digest)
{
    /* Creating Id Digest. */
    int rc = 0, i;
    unsigned char idDgst[21] = { '\0' };
    char buffer[3] = { '\0' };

    rc = SHA1(cid, len, idDgst) == NULL ? -1 : 0;
    for(i = 0; !rc && (i < sizeof(idDgst)-1); i++)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "%02X", idDgst[i]);
        strncat(digest, buffer, 3);
    }
    return rc == 0;
}
```

C++ code was shared with me to implement in Java. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which library is your SHA1 from? I can't reproduce the issue for `openssl/sha.h`, i.e. the result corresponds to that of the Java-code. Post also the entire C-code i.e. the `hash_SHA1`-call including all parameters used.

Comment: C++ uses openssl

Comment: As I said, I can't reproduce the problem for this. Post a complete and executable C++-code that causes the problem on your machine.

Comment: This isn't very useful to anybody else given the solution, glad you found a solution, but it is better to delete the question & answer.

Comment: Note that you should *always*  indicate a character encoding in `getBytes` even if it is just `StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`. Well, unless your code is really dependent on the default platform encoding but that counts for maybe 1% of the code out there.

Answer (score 0):

There was extra char getting appended to the input string from where the function was called in the C code. Giving the right input gave the exact same result. Thanks @Topaco, for validating the code.

Answer (score -1):

Java can use 16-bit for each character in String. C++ - not.

Comment: True, but since either Windows1252 or UTF-8 (Linux, Android) is used as default 8 bit encoding, that's unlikely to be the source of the issue.